# Symfony 2 and PHP-EWS

Tags: php, symfony, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have a Symfony 2.0.17 project and I'd like to use php-ews in order to interact with an Exchange Server.
The problem is that I don't know to integrate php-ews in my project.
I downloaded a PSR-0 compliant version ([here](https://github.com/beraneck/php-ews))
I modified the app/autoload.php file like this :

```
'PhpEws'           => __DIR__.'/../vendor/PhpEws/PhpEws',
```

Here an example :

```
use PhpEws; 
use ExchangeWebServices;
use EWS_Exception;
use NTLMSoapClient;
use NTLMSoapClient_Exchange;
use EWSType_FindItemType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;

...

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $user, $password, $version);
```

And I got the following error

```
'Class ExchangeWebServices not found'
```

Someone has an idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
use PhpEws\ExchangeWebServices; 

...

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $user, $password, $version);
```